# delete any event javascript from a string

Tags: php, javascript, html, xss

`Is there an easy way to remove with php`  any type of event HTML in php string. For example for events  **submit,mouseOut,mouseOver,click,blur,focus,etc.** to prevent javascript injection, for cases like these:
is There an easy way to remove **with php**  any type of event HTML in php srtring. For example for events  **submit,mouseOut,mouseOver,click,blur,focus,etc.** to prevent javascript injection, for cases like these:

```
$text= 'mi secure html <div id="javascript_injection" onfocus=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode}></div> <p> Im interested in showing the resulting html </p>'

echo $text = 'mi secure html <div id="javascript_injection" > example </div> <b> Im interested in showing the resulting html </b>
```

I'm also interested in showing this:

```
'mi secure html <div id="javascript_injection" > example </div> <b> Im interested in showing the resulting html </b>
```

**PD:I can not escape all the text or remove all tags because there are parts that if I want to show in html.`Imagine you want to show a user creates html to another and want to avoid the injection of javascript`**

Comment: What is this supposed to be? PHP? JavaScript? HTML?

Comment: If your code can be "hacked" through javascript, then you better change the code...

Comment: Im sorry,I was editing when you answered the question, It just republish Pay attention to the bold.

Comment: If you want to allow `img` elements, you should check `src` (and other non-obvious constructs) as well, as it may contain JavaScript. There are many other edge cases as well. See [XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). As Wayne Whitty already said, where is this text coming from?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like a simple whitelisting solution, nothing difficult.

Comment: @Jack: I'm afraid it's not that simple, if he wants to prevent XSS without using `htmlspecialchars`. See the cheat sheet I linked to.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel A DOMDocument based solution should work just fine though, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: sorry if someone misunderstand,I know there are programs, plugins, etc to avoid this Injection javascript. But the question is clear. Just wanted to know if there is any way to avoid at least php events.if anyone knows something. I try to make a first barrier for Injection javascript. :)

Comment: @Martin: only disallowing JavaScript event attributes is totally not sufficient to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve this kind of problem is through whitelisting instead of blacklisting. The idea is that you define what tags / attributes you allow, instead of trying to filter out bad things.

A good library that handles this is http://htmlpurifier.org/. You can customize it to make it allow the things you want to keep.

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$dirty_html = '<a href="test.html" onclick="alert()">Test</a>'

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);

echo $clean_html
```

Output:

```
<a href="test.html">Test</a>
```

Comment: Looks great, but does it disallow `<img src="javascript:alert(0)">`?

Comment: There is a demo page to test: http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php (It filters out the entire tag)

Comment: I'm not going to manually test every edge case, but it does a pretty good job indeed.

Comment: Here is a list with tests: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/smoketests/xssAttacks.php